# How to build plugins for Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-plugin

I'm not asking about gradle plugins, I'm asking how could you change the IDE itself?, like adding a new menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio is based on the IntelliJ Platform, so all of the information for building IntelliJ IDEA plugins applies to Android Studio as well. See [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment) for the IntelliJ IDEA plugin development documentation.